# How can I see the SQL rows in Oracle APEX SQL Workshop? (Oracle APEX Ver.21.1)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I can't enter SQL commands in SQL builder's either "SQL Commands" and "SQL Scripts".

The row number is not displayed on the input pane.

For example, if you open SQL Workshop's SQL Commands, you will see from the top a schema selection row labeled "SQL Commands", a row labeled "Language: SQL Row: 10", and tool rows such as Undo / Redo. The input line that should be underneath is empty but does not accept any input.

Comment: seems like a browser problem.

Comment: That's right!
I changed my browser to Chrome and the cache disappeared and it works correctly.
Thank you!!